# Importing a Word format CV into the StackOverflowCareer site

Tags: feature-request, jobs, cv

I just joined SO so that I could post a cv on the career site.  But it looks like I have to retype all of my cv info into the career cv form.  Isn't there a way to import the data from a Word doc?

Comment: I don't believe so, but IIRC there is a way to import from LinkedIn or Facebook. I've never tried it, though.

Comment: @Jon - I tried the beta version when it just presented the information to you rather than actually importing it. It did a good job.

Comment: Yes: `Ctrl`+`C`, `Ctrl`+`V`, repeat.

Comment: Wow, bummer.  I understand wanting to keep a consistent format for all the cv's, so a form makes sense.  But lots of employer career sites can import a Word doc and populate the form for you.  Why can't SO do that too?  That's all I'm asking.  Ctrl-V/Ctrl-C for every form field is so tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the desire.

We chatted about this and think it really unlikely that a Word import would be anything but a mess, unfortunately. We could grab the raw text of course but don't see how we would parse it in to "positions", "locations", etc, with any sort of accuracy. You'd end up spending just as much time fixing the import. :)

Are you aware of someone doing a good job of this?

Comment: My career service website at my University did a great job of auto filling stuff from my resume.  I believe my current employer also filled some info after I uploaded my resume.